# How to replace the usage of System.out or System.err by a logger?

Tags: java, logging, println, system.out

I have a simple `if` condition in which I use `System.out.println`.
I would like to know how can I modify the code in order to replace this usage of a `system.out` by a logger ?

```
if(myVar.getDate().equals(20141127) && myVar.getNumber().equals(1)) {
                System.out.println("");
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at `log4j`

Comment: are you looking for 
`System#setOut` & `System#setErr`!

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder, I am not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: In the short term, you could redirect the output from System.out and System.err to a file, which becomes your log file. Then you can embark on a mission to replace those calls with Log4J or SLF4J calls that will allow you to log at different levels. Maybe even look at AOP to add the logging in for you.

Comment: Example : `System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("file.txt")));`

Comment: I don't know why this is closed. The question it's marked as a duplicate of is entirely talking of something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some logger utility to log the details.

Have a look at [Apache Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)

The logging is as simple as

```
log.debug("This is an debug message");
```

where log is an instance of logger

For sample code you can look into this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm)

Comment: Should I create my logger outside of the `if` condition or inside ?

Comment: @hacks4life Could you please look into the tutorial I have mentioned. I have made an edit to the answer

Comment: Done. I do not get what's in the `getLogger()` method. What am I supposed to put inside ? My own class right ?

Comment: @hacks4life Yes, put your class name there. It means that the logger is specific for your class.

Comment: There is a simple & straightforward logger built-in (since Java 7):

Assuming the Class you are logging from is named "LoggingExample", do this:



`Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingExample.class.getSimpleName());
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Message to log");`

You'll need the following imports (some IDEs can auto-import):

`import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;`

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'debug' in 'Log4j'

Comment: How to show message to user when there is an issue in log4j.